# Errors that I don't understand

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to write a code from the following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mAmZIRfJBs&t=197s
In my opinion I completely wrote it the same way, but it still gives an error. Can someone explain to me why Spyder(Python 3.7) does this.
This is my code:

I tried using another input function so raw_input instead of input. I also tried changing my working directory and saving the document

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 29 14:47:27 2019

@author: johan
"""

import random

restaurantsList = ['boloco', 'clover', 'sweetgreens']

def pickRestaurant():
    print(restaurantsList[random.randint(0,2)])

def addRestaurant(name):
    restaurantsList.append(name)

def removeRestaurant(name):
    restaurantsList.remove(name)

def listRestaurant():
    for restaurant in restaurantsList:
        print(restaurant)

while True: 
    print('''

   [1] - List restaurant
   [2] - Add restaurant
   [3] - Remove restaurant
   [4] - Pick restaurant
   [5] - Exit

''')
   selection = raw_input(prompt='Please select an option: ')

   if selection == '1':
       print('')
       listRestaurant()
   elif selection == '2':
       inName = raw_input(prompt='Type name of the restaurant that you want to add: ')
       addRestaurant(inName)
   elif selection == '3':
       inName = raw_input(prompt='Type name of the restaurant that you want to remove: ')
       removeRestaurant(inName)
   elif selection == '4':
       pickRestaurant()
   elif selection == '5':
       break
```

and this is the error

```
    runfile('C:/Users/johan/Desktop/Unie jaar 2/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/johan/Desktop/Unie jaar 2')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\johan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-93-2d7193d6cafb>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/johan/Desktop/Unie jaar 2/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/johan/Desktop/Unie jaar 2')

  File "C:\Users\johan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\johan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/johan/Desktop/Unie jaar 2/untitled2.py", line 35
selection = raw_input(prompt='Please select an option: ')
                                                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

The code should give a list of restaurant is 1 is put in. You are able to add a restaurant to the list if 2 is put in. 3 is like to but then you remove. 4 picks a random restaurant from the list. 5 does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's imperative that you indent correctly in Python, as such;

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 29 14:47:27 2019

@author: johan
"""

import random

restaurantsList = ['boloco', 'clover', 'sweetgreens']

def pickRestaurant():
  print(restaurantsList[random.randint(0,2)])

def addRestaurant(name):
  restaurantsList.append(name)

def removeRestaurant(name):
  restaurantsList.remove(name)

def listRestaurant():
  for restaurant in restaurantsList:
    print(restaurant)

while True: 
  print('''
  [1] - List restaurant
  [2] - Add restaurant
  [3] - Remove restaurant
  [4] - Pick restaurant
  [5] - Exit
  ''')
  selection = input('Please select an option: ')
  if selection == '1':
    print('')
    listRestaurant()
  elif selection == '2':
    inName = input('Type name of the restaurant that you want to add: ')
    addRestaurant(inName)
  elif selection == '3':
    inName = input('Type name of the restaurant that you want to remove: ')
    removeRestaurant(inName)
  elif selection == '4':
    pickRestaurant()
  elif selection == '5':
    break
```

Python is indentation sensitive, and when creating a function or any statements you need to indent any code inside that function or you will get the error you have above.

Additional note: You're using `print()` which is python2 and `raw_input` which is python3, so I've assumed Python3 and changed the `raw_input()` for `input()`.

Comment: Sorry, the first was just an example, I've updated my answer to include your whole code as there were other sections that needed indentation as well

Comment: maybe it has something to do with my settings in Spyder?

Comment: Did you copy and paste my example? Because there's probably a mix of spaces and tabs.. Go through your original code and add the indentation (if you use tabs use tabs, otherwise 4 spaces) where it's needed and it should work

Comment: @MichielMeindertsma copy and paste the example in my answer now, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: yeah i did, but i know went over it again

Comment: What errors do you have? Because it runs perfectly on my machine. Are you using python 2?

Comment: Here's an example replit for you of the same code but with correct indentation; https://repl.it/@Nordle/replit which works without issues

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 spaces before `print` statement within `while` loop, but all other lines in that loop have 3 spaces indent only, starting from `selection = raw_input...`

You should add a space at the start for every line starting from `selection = raw_input...` and below.